# Ignoring SSL exception in Jmeter UI Recording

Tags: ssl, jmeter

I have to perform a load test on a env whose URL can be accessed as https://loadenv.com/home

When I access the URL from browser everything looks fine. However when I proxy it to use for Jmeter recording, I am getting error as below

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:2023)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1125)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:436)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:294)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.MeasuringConnectionManager$MeasuredConnection.open(MeasuringConnectionManager.java:107)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:643)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:479)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:805)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.executeRequest(HTTPHC4Impl.java:517)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:331)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:74)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1146)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.Proxy.run(Proxy.java:240)
```

I understand the env did not have the proper SSL setup needed. I tried some solutions suggested on how to bypass the SSL setup for recording but I haven't succeeded.

Any suggestions please

Answer (score 0):

JMeter troubleshooting options:

1. Clear your browsing data, better completely.
2. Uninstall and reinstall JMeter dummy certificate

---

Alternative recording options are:

- [Badboy](http://www.badboy.com.au/) tool has an option to export recordings as JMeter tests
- [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) debugging proxy can be [configured](http://www.perftesting.co.uk/creating-jmeter-test-plans-with-fiddler/2013/03/01/) to generate JMeter test plans
- [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732579-Chrome-Extension) allows recording a JMeter test right from Google Chrome browser without having to worry about proxies, SSL certificates, etc.

Comment: Thanks. I will try that. I actually tried the Blazemeter Chrome extension and the recording do happened successfully and I downloaded the .jmx file. But when I used that .jmx in jmeter or even in blazemeter the result showed ssl error.